# how to get the value of a textarea generated by for loop/javascript

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I have to insert the value from a text field into the database on button click. These text fields are generated by user input/click. So if I assign an id or class it will be the same for all the elements. Even if I make it unique how would I get the value of the text fields corresponding to the button click. Code looks something like

```
 <% for(var i=0;i < post_data.length;i++){%>
 <div class="post-comment">
          <textarea class="comment-box" name="" id="" cols="80" rows="1" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btnComment" id="<%= post_data[i].post_id %>" name="">
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
          </button>
  </div>
  <%}%>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4s9I.png)

My bad i could not make the things clear. I want the value from textarea as i click on the curved arrow button.

Comment: Your question is not clear to understand.

Comment: Please look at the code. I just updated

Comment: on click of btnComment I need to get the value of comment-box

Comment: _So if I assign an id or class it will be the same for all the elements_.

Asigh **index** as as an **id**. Similarly how you did for the button. `<textarea id="<%= i %>"></textarea>`

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: <textarea id="<%= i %>"></textarea> then how would I come to know the id of the textarea corresponding to the btnComment clicked

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery method as follows:

```
$("button[name^=t]").click(function(){
     //process
}
```

The above method will be invoked whenever a `button` whose name starts with `'t'` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add any identifier, Just grab the data of the previous element using Jquery using the following code.

```
  $(document).on('click','.btnComment',function(){
        var CommentText = $(this).prev().val(); 
        alert(CommentText);
    });
```

Check out the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gokulmaha/whje4vx0/7/)

Comment: its good for existing element but as soon as a new element is generated it shows 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do it without jquery:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // init listeners for buttons

  const value = event.target.parentNode // get to the textarea through the parent (div)
    .querySelector('textarea').value;
  console.log(value)
}))
```

```html
<div class="post-comment">
  <textarea class="comment-box" name="" id="" cols="80" rows="1" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btnComment" id="" name="">
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>1
          </button>
</div>
<div class="post-comment">
  <textarea class="comment-box" name="" id="" cols="80" rows="1" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btnComment" id="" name="">
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>2
          </button>
</div>
<div class="post-comment">
  <textarea class="comment-box" name="" id="" cols="80" rows="1" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btnComment" id="" name="">3
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
          </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this snippet. You can read text using prev().

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 alert($( this ).prev().val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-comment">
          <textarea class="comment-box" name="" id="" cols="80" rows="1" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btnComment" id="" name="">
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>1
          </button>
  </div>
 <div class="post-comment">
          <textarea class="comment-box" name="" id="" cols="80" rows="1" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btnComment" id="" name="">
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>2
          </button>
  </div>
 <div class="post-comment">
          <textarea class="comment-box" name="" id="" cols="80" rows="1" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btnComment" id="" name="">3
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
          </button>
  </div>
```